# Android TaskStackBuilder and toolbar icon blink

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, history

My code of notification:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setContentText("test")
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setTicker("Powiadomienie: test");

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

Intent ia = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
Intent ib = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
Intent ic = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);

stackBuilder.addNextIntent(ia);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(ib);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(ic);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Order of activity is:
ActivityA -> ActivityB -> ActivityC

When shows ActivityC stack is build from end like in code. On back button show ActivityB and ActivityA.

On video shows what's happen:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YP_-KE-fuCg

When shows last activity (ActivityA) toolbar icon show standard icon and after shows icon of activity. This icon is set in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="ActivityA" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher2"></activity>

<activity android:parentActivityName=".ActivityA" android:name="ActivityB" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher2">
    <meta-data 
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".ActivityA" />
</activity>

<activity android:parentActivityName=".ActivityB" android:name="ActivityC" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher2">
    <meta-data 
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".ActivityB" />
</activity>
```

I cant find answer how to fix it. I dont want to blink icon. Someone have solution of this problem?

Here is sample code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6099319/NotificationTest.zip